# Excel macro to insert function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will place a formula under a column of numbers, such as sum or average. I came up with this:

```
Sub foo()
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)
End Sub
```

This function will find the sum and place it under the last number in a column of data that you have selected the top of.  That works but it is not dynamic, the new value is just a value, if I change one of the numbers in the column, the cell holding the sum does not change.  So I'm trying to place the actual function in the cell.  This is what I have currently:

```
Sub foo()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Formula = "=Sum(ActiveCell:ActiveCell.End(xlUp))"
End Sub
```

This time I started at the bottom, the active cell is currently intended to be the last value in the column.  No errors are detected but the output is bad, "#NAME".  I tried playing with the quotes but didn't get anything.  For example:

```
Sub foo()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Formula = "=Sum(" & ActiveCell:ActiveCell.End(xlUp) & ")"
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to get the `Address()` of the range you want to sum, and use that in the formula.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Address()` will give you the address of the range you want to sum. Substitiute that in the formula instead of `ActiveCell:ActiveCell.End(xlUp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gary's Student's answer is very close but not quite there, this is what I ended up with:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp)).Address(0,0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Formula = "=SUM(" & s & ")"
End Sub
```

If you select the last cell in a column of data it will place the sum formula right under it, and its dynamic so you're free to change the data.

EDIT: added `(0,0)` onto address so its dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Address
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & s & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: I get run-time error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error when I run that.

Answer (score 1):

If your data always starts at row 1 then you can use the macro as such:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).ForumulaR1C1 = "=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()) & "":"" & ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))"
```